# SQL Server ISNULL / Coalesce still returning empty lists

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, coalesce

I have a table called `Users` with a column called `Limit` that holds integer values. Every user has a Limit but non-registered users have a default limit of 1.

I want to run a simple query that tells me the Limit for a user if they are registered or defaults to 1 if they are not a registered users, however when I run a query with either `ISNULL` or `Coalesce` as written below:

```
SELECT coalesce(Limit,1) AS limit 
FROM User 
WHERE userID = 'testUser'
```

The query will work fine if I query on an existing user but will return an empty list if I try a non-registered user [it should return a single row with a value of 1].

Using `ISNULL` instead of coalesce produces the same result. Every example I have found of `ISNULL` and coalesce look that way. What am I missing?

Comment: Share table structure and sample data. I guess that your query does not return any row for non-registered users so everything works as it should

Comment: Sounds like the User doesn't exist in the `User` table then. What does a simple `SELECT *` for the userID in question return?

Comment: Non-registered users do not exist in the Users table. Specifically, I'd use their IP as a userID [this would be stored in another table for other purposes]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`coalesce` operates on an returned value, and evaluates if it's `null` or not. In your case, a non-existent just doesn't have a row, so, as you noted, it will not work.

You can, however, emulate this behavior with a left join:

```
SELECT    COALESCE(b_limit, a_limit) AS limit
FROM      (SELECT 1 AS a_limit) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT limit AS b_limit
           FROM   user
           WHERE  userID = 'testUser') b ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: `COALESCE(a_limit, b_limit)`  will always return 1. Change the order inside `COALESCE`

Comment: @lad2025 eap! Indeed! Thanks for noticing. That was careless on my part.

Comment: @ConnorU definitely not my day... Can't just omit the `on` clause. See edited answer.

Comment: I just saw your edit. Yeah the join conditions were missing. This works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

may be that.. if subselect result is null, then result is 1

```
SELECT coalesce((SELECT Limit 
                   FROM User 
                  WHERE userID = 'testUser'), 1) AS limit
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. At first glance it seemed it would not work but since the select returning no row is a subquery as a column it will work.

Comment: if subquery don't return any row value was NULL and result COALESCE is 1